# Counting pairwise combinations Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following "lookup" table, which is essentially a code denoting the pairwise presence of two different companies

| Company 1 | Company 2 | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Murphy | Heathcote | 1 |
| Wolff | Kassulke | 2 |
| Murphy | Kassulke | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Farrell | Padberg | 72 |

and then
I have
a table of locations and companies, not one-to-one, for example

| city | company |
| --- | --- |
| Belfast | Heathcote |
| Belfast | Murphy |
| London | Farrell |

How would I generate a table with city as the primary key, and the code as a field? I can only think of horrible way involving 72 case statements.

Comment: What you are really thinking is not really a horrible way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Table2.City,Table1.code
from Table1 join Table2 
on table1.company1= table2.company
```

or

Adding the code column(table1) to the second table would really help to simplify it. Given the second table is the reference table, which will rarely change.